# How to Automate SharePoint Record Updates

Tags: development, powershell

So we have an inventory list with details about each item, mostly drop down menus and check boxes, some comments and descriptions. These records are in SharePoint. Sometimes we need to update multiple items in there in addition to a large number of other steps and I am trying to automate most of these steps including the updates to their SharePoint record. What is the best way to go about this in PowerShell from any remote computer?

Would I connect to the database, find the record and and update the record there? Is there an easier way? I tried finding PowerShell CLI tools for SharePoint but I don't see them available anywhere.

For example, I might want to update this field here:

[image]

EDIT:

Here's the code I've tried but it does nothing at all for some reason, not even an error which means it's finding the list but... It's returning 0 items found for whatever reason.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the context
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp.mydomain.com/sites/ts/it/ITG");
        // Get the list
        List recordsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ServerInventory_Official-List");
        // Get specific item by id number
        CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = recordsList.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Number of items: " + items.Count);
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem["HostName"]);
            if (listItem["HostName"].ToString() == "myserverhostname")
            {
                listItem["ActiveFlag"] = "Decommissioned";
                Console.WriteLine("This Happened");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic approach. This could be made more robust by passing variables to `-ArgumentList` in the `Invoke-Command` and then setting variables inside the script.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SEVERNAME -Verbose -ScriptBlock {
  $VerbosePreference='Continue'

  if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
  {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -Verbose
  }

  $Web = Get-SPWeb http://your.sp.web.url
  $List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList("LISTNAME")
  # By ID
  $ListItem = $List.GetItemByUniqueId("UNIQUEID")
  # By Title - Or any field as long as it is unique - if not unique, handle with a loop
  # $ListItem = $List.Items | ? {$_["Title"] -eq "UNIQUE TITLE"}

  $ListItem["ActiveFlag"] = "Decommissioned"

  $ListItem.Update()
}
```

Example with args

```
$FlagValue = "Decommissioned"
$IdsToUpdate = "10","13","11"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SEVERNAME -ArgumentList $FlagValue,$IdsToUpdate -Verbose -ScriptBlock {
  $FlagValue = $args[0]
  $IdsToUpdate = $args[1]

  $VerbosePreference='Continue'

  if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
  {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -Verbose
  }

  $Web = Get-SPWeb http://your.sp.web.url
  $List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList("LISTNAME")

  foreach($Id in $IdsToUpdate)
  {
    $ListItem = $List.GetItemByUniqueId("UNIQUEID")
    $ListItem["ActiveFlag"] = $FlagValue
    $ListItem.Update()
  }
}
```

You could easily pass in list names and other variables that you might get outside of the scriptblock itself.

Hope this helps.

If you don't have accesss to the SharePoint Servers, this same thing can be accomplished with CSOM in a Console Application.

```
// Get the context
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://your.sp.web.url");
// Get the list
List recordsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LISTNAME");
// Get specific item by id number
ListItem item = recordsList.GetItemById(ID);
// Change item & Update
item["ActiveFlag"] = "Decommissioned";
item.Update();
// ExecuteQuery
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can build a loop similar to the one in the powershell above. You may want to look at PnP materials for more ideas.

Ref: [Basic Operations Using CSOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Comment: You should not mess with the database directly, unless you like being in an unsupported (by Microsoft) state.

Comment: I wanna try this, the thing is I can't seem to add or get any powershell snapins. It can't find cmdlets called Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell on my machine. How does one install them on a machine that is not an SP server?

Comment: You can't. That is why this is run inside ``Invoke-Command``. It opens a remote session on the server and runs the commands there. You need to have access to the SharePoint Server and have to have PowerShell rights in order to work with SharePoint PowerShell.

Comment: I added a CSOM example, Javascript or REST could do this too.

Comment: Wow you think by now they'd have some powershell cmdlets that work on any computer, like Citrix, Nutanix and VMWare have all done. Thanks for the help, I'll try REST if the invoke doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah. It's basically the difference between Client Side OM and Server Side OM. The powershell library exposes nearly everything, so its restricted to those who are allowed into the server (and allowed to powershell)... You would think there would be a CSOM version of powershell, but not at this point.

Comment: So I've been trying to make this work. I got the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client installed via Nuget into VS 2017 on a new forms app and your last chunk of code above appears to be valid, and may work, but the GetItemById method wants a string, but not sure how it's supposed to know the ID, I don't know the ID, just the title. Also, the moment I installed the sharepoint client, VS says Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Form can't be designed.

Comment: Try a console app. Also id you don't know the ID, you have to have some other way to pick which item you want to change... If you want to bulk edit ALL the items look at [SharePoint list item tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#sharepoint-list-item-tasks).  That shows how to get all the items and loop through. You could add some sort of test to find specific items.  You can also design a CamlQuery that will target the items you want rather than ALL.

Comment: The Form class you are trying to edit is not the same as designing a Form app in VS... The Form Class in  Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Form is literally for designing a custom form for the SharePoint list to use rather than the default one (this would only be in some sort of Add-In that you might build).

Comment: I'm also noticing that the "List" referred to is not the same as a regular List one would normally use in C#. Not trying to bulk edit necessarily, just edit a single item in the list. This is all very frustrating. There has to be a way to get the ID of an item in a list if all you have is its name, the link you click in the web page to get to the record (i.e. hostname). I assume the list title is the title of a list of items, in my case "ServerInventory_Official-List". All I have is the hostname at first.

Comment: See edit for what I tried in the console app. It doesn't get an error but doesn't seem to do anything at all either. It seems to find the list though.

Comment: in the loop, after you update the listItem do listItem.Update() and then outside the loop context.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: if you have the url to an item, the url will have the param ID=2 (or whatever the id is).

Comment: you can filter the request up front with a specific caml query rather than the create all items version ``camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRefName='HostName'/><Eq><Value Type='Text'>myserverhostname</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";``